# C function to print 2D array of chars

Tags: c, arrays, function, warnings, getchar

Im trying to learn C, surely using the hard way and cant figure out this one error, could someone help? :-)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define max_X 15
#define max_Y 15

int x, y;

char Array[max_Y][max_X];

void displayArray(void){
 for (y = 0; y < max_Y; y++) {
    for (x = 0; x < max_X; x++) {
        printf("%c",Array[y][x]);
    }
    printf("\n");
 }
}



int main(void){
 for (y = 0; y < max_Y; y++) {
    for (x = 0; x < max_X; x++) {
        Array[y][x] = '.';
    }
 }
 displayArray;
 getchar;
 return(0);
}
```

Im trying to print out char array containing just dot characters using function. When i run it, there is just blank cmd and return value 0. I keep getting warnings about statements with no effect on these two lines:

```
 displayArray;
 getchar;
```

Can someone help? or give me a link to similar one where i can find answer to my problem? I was looking around but couldn't find anything i could compare to mine and understand at least a little.

Comment: try `displayArray()` to _call_ the functions. Else it is the function pointer.

Comment: note that you'll only get zeros in your array.

Comment: Thank you very much! All the time i thought that when there is void or nothing in the brackets, that they dont need them. Thank you very much!

Comment: Ada language doesn't need them where there's no parameter, but C/C++ most of other languages do. You're welcome

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: Neither does Pascal.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis maybe thats why i made this mistake, we learn this ancient language in our school, i think its cool and easy to learn on, but theres no more use for that.

Comment: The array will be initialized with all values equal to \0, which will not result in a visible value. You need to put some characters into Array before you can print them out.

Comment: @JimRogers Thanks, edited! :-)

Comment: `% gcc -Wall` would spit out warnings: `warning: statement with no effect [-Wunused-value]: displayArray;`

Comment: @AnttiHaapala My IDE did exactly that, but i wasnt sure where to search for mistake.

Comment: @RollAndSchullz: Pascal is not ancient. Delphi and FreePascal are quite modern (more than, say, Java) and in use in many places.

Comment: @RollAndSchullz: Most compilers will also tell you where exactly an error or a warning applies. Doesn't you IDE read that info and use it to display the exact place of error?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use parentheses even when the function you're using takes no arguments. So,

```
displayArray;
getchar;
```

should be:

```
displayArray();
getchar();
```

Also, return isn't a function. It's a keyword, so you can do:

```
return 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `displayArray();`
You should not call function like this `displayArray`;you can use this while providing address of function to function pointer.